# Как прокрутить страницу до элемента нажатием на него же?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, прокрутка

Есть страница с различной информацией и картинками в `<li>`-элементах. Нужно с помощью JavaScript, при клике на картинку(в примере это иконки инстаграмма) прокручивать страницу к верху, прижимая картинку по которой кликнули к верху окна браузера. (Прошу не путать с прокруткой страницы до верха страницы!).

Помогите, в JavaScript не силен. Прошерстил инет, но не нашел ничего.
Править HTML нельзя!
[ПРИМЕР на CodePen](https://codepen.io/david-shalvashvili/pen/qLYebr)

Comment: `scrollTop` используйте, плохо искали. В вашем примере ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
$('.pic-view-item').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.r-photo-list ul {
    height: 50px;
}
.r-photo-list li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.r-photo-list li img {
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dd class="r-photo-list">
<ul class="util-clearfix">
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
</ul>
</dd>
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.
<dd class="r-photo-list">
<ul class="util-clearfix">
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
</ul>
</dd>
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.
<dd class="r-photo-list">
<ul class="util-clearfix">
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
</ul>
</dd>
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.
<dd class="r-photo-list">
<ul class="util-clearfix">
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
<li class="pic-view-item"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/25/00/02/instagram-2258219__340.png"></li>
</ul>
</dd>
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis officiis dolor suscipit odio laborum ut quaerat! Error vitae eos, minima sapiente quasi sit voluptatem officiis quia in aut, commodi quod.
```

Comment: Круто, это именно то что нужно, но возможно ли провернуть это без редактирования HTML? Допустим есть только один index.js подключенный к html,который можно править. Вот именно через этот js пробую реализовать эту идею.

Comment: @DavidShalvashvili, так а я и не редактировал Ваш html - только скрипт добавил и всё

Comment: jquery.min.js вот этот js вы подключаете в html. А без него код уже не работает. Но так как править я не могу html, следовательно и подключить js не могу((.

Comment: @DavidShalvashvili, ничто не мешает Вам подключить jquery посредством js: qaru.site/questions/54354/how-to-add-jquery-in-js-file

Answer (score 1):

Яваскрипт тут не нужен вообще. Прокрутка элемента до верха окна браузера - фича HTML, изобретенная еще при царе горохе. Это делается внутренними гиперссылками вида `<a href="#some_name">...</a>`, при клике на которые происходит прокрутка до элемента, имеющего атрибут `name` со значением `some_name`. Если требуется прокрутка до элемента при клике на него же, то нужно просто задать ему и `href`, и `name`, например:

```
<a name="image8" href="#image8"><img src="..."></a>
```

Вот ваш пен, сделал для последнего изображения (розоватое): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRxEdX

Comment: Простите, забыл указать в вопросе, что код html править нельзя. Поэтому я и ищу возможность это сделать с помощью скрипта. Про Якоря прекрасно осведомлен. Спасибо что откликнулись, но это не то!